# Using Java and IText, how to extract AcroForm field names from a PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm looking for a simple API example, that reads a PDF file / template as an input, and iterates over the fields defined in the PDF form (I think it is called AcroForm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution

```
public static void scanFields(String path) throws IOException {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);
    AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.getAcroFields();
    HashMap<String,AcroFields.Item> fields = acroFields.getFields();
    Set<Entry<String, Item>> entrySet = fields.entrySet();
    for (Entry<String, Item> entry : entrySet) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
    }
}
```